# java how to delete digits after comma in double data type

Tags: java, integer, double

so for example what I have and what I want it to, first numbers are double and I would like them to be integer but with no zeros

---

2.00   -> 2

---

5.012 -> 5

---

I tried with this, but still doesn't work

```
if(result % 1 == 0){
    String temp = String.valueOf(result);
    int tempInt = Integer.parseInt(temp);
    tekst.setText(String.valueOf(tempInt));

    }else {
     tekst.setText(String.valueOf(result));
     num1 = 0;
     num2 = 0;
     result = 0;
}
```

result variable is double,
also this shows after compiling

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "887.0"
```

Comment: `String.format("%.0f", result)`  - since you want to **format** a floating point number with no digits after the radix point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i would do.

```
double num1 = 2.3;
double num2 = 4.5;
```

Later...

```
    int num11 = (int) num1;
    int num22 = (int) num2;
    System.out.println(num11 + ", " + num22 + ".");
```

The result would be:

2, 4.

That's all.

Answer (score 2):

There is a *caveat* that you need to be aware about since you're trying to use an intermediate `int` variable:

- The range of `double` values is far broader than the range of `long` (and `int` obviously). So by converting a `double` into a `long` and then again to `double` you might lose the data.

Here are some ways how it can be done *without losing* the data:

**1.** Modular division:

```
double num = 59.012;

double wholeNum2 = num - num % 1;
```

**2.** Static method [`Math.floor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#floor(double)):

```
double num = 59.012;

double wholeNum = Math.floor(num);
```

**3.** [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#method-summary) class, that allow to specify a string pattern and format a number accordingly:

```
double num = 59.012;

NumberFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0");
double wholeNum = Double.parseDouble(format.format(num)); // parsing the formatted string
```

All examples above will give you the output `59.0` is you print the variable `wholeNum`.

When you need to obtain a `double` value as a result with the fractional part dropped, options **1** and **2** are preferable. But a string representing this number will still contain a dot and one zero `.0` at the end.

But if you need to get the result as a `String`  containing only the *integer part* of a `double` number, then `DecimalFormat` (*as well `String.format()` that was mentioned in the comments*) will help you to get rid of the *fractional part* completely.

```
NumberFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0");

System.out.println(format.format(59.012));
```

*Output:*

```
59
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you maybe parsing a double string so 10.0001 with an int parse? Because it will recognize that it's not an int and throw an error. You should first parse it to a double and then cast that to an int.

```
    //if you want to parse it from a string
    String doubleString = "100.0001";

    double parsedDoubleValue = Double.parseDouble(doubleString);
    System.out.println("Parsed double value: " + parsedDoubleValue);
    
    int castedValue = (int) parsedDoubleValue;
    System.out.println("Casted double value to int: " + castedValue);
    
    //if you have to original double
    double doubleValue = 1.0001;
    int intValue = (int)doubleValue;

    System.out.println(intValue);
```

Comment: casting it to an int worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

use (Integer)(Math.floor(*insert your double here*))
The floor(double x) method is already built into the math class, and returns a double, for instance 5.5 becomes 5.0
Then we just instance that number as an Integer (or alternatively an int) and we get out result

Comment: `incompatible types: double cannot be converted to java.lang.Integer` - you probably meant `(int) Math.floor(...)`

Answer (score -1):

According to the method documentation for parseInt(String s):

```
Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value. The resulting integer value is returned, exactly as if the argument and the radix 10 were given as arguments to the parseInt(String, int) method.
Params:
s – a String containing the int representation to be parsed
Returns:
the integer value represented by the argument in decimal.
Throws:
NumberFormatException – if the string does not contain a parsable integer.
```

The number is a double and contains characters that are not parsable ie"." so it thows error.

You may consider:

```
int tempInt = Integer.parseInt(temp.split("\\.")[0]);
```

or just directly skip parsing the Integer:

```
tekst.setText(temp.split("\\.")[0]);
```

Comment: this is a bad answer... why? Is using .split() not efficient or something?